# How do I specify the linker path in Rust?

Tags: rust, static-linking, dynamic-linking, rust-cargo

I'm trying to link a Rust program with [libsoundio](http://libsound.io/). I'm using Windows and there's a GCC binary download available. I can link it like this if I put it in the same folder as my project:

```
#[link(name = ":libsoundio-1.1.0/i686/libsoundio.a")]
#[link(name = "ole32")]
extern {
    fn soundio_version_string() -> *const c_char;
}
```

But I really want to specify `#[link(name = "libsoundio")]` or even `#[link(name = "soundio")]`, and then provide a linker path somewhere else.

Where can I specify that path?

I tried the `rustc-link-search` suggestion as follows:

```
#[link(name = "libsoundio")]
#[link(name = "ole32")]
extern {
    fn soundio_version_string() -> *const c_char;
}
```

And in `.cargo/config`:

```
[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu.libsoundio]
rustc-link-search = ["libsoundio-1.1.0/i686"]
rustc-link-lib = ["libsoundio.a"]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.libsoundio]
rustc-link-search = ["libsoundio-1.1.0/x86_64"]
rustc-link-lib = ["libsoundio.a"]
```

But it still only passes `"-l" "libsoundio"` to gcc and fails with the same `ld: cannot find -llibsoundio`. Am I missing something really obvious? The docs seem to suggest this should work.

Answer (score 21):

As stated in the [documentation for a build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#outputs-of-the-build-script):

> All the lines printed to stdout by a build script [... starting] with `cargo:` is interpreted directly by Cargo [...] `rustc-link-search` indicates the specified value should be passed to the compiler as a `-L` flag.

In your **Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "link-example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]
build = "build.rs"
```

And your **build.rs**:

```
fn main() {
    println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=C:\Rust\linka\libsoundio-1.1.0\i686");
}
```

Note that your build script can use all the power of Rust and can output different values depending on target platform (e.g. 32- and 64-bit).

Finally, your code:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_char;
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[link(name = "soundio")]
extern {
    fn soundio_version_string() -> *const c_char;
}

fn main() {
    let v = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(soundio_version_string()) };
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

The proof is in the pudding:

```
$ cargo run
    Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
     Running `target\debug\linka.exe`
"1.0.3"
```

---

Ideally, you will create a `soundio-sys` package, using [the convention for `*-sys` packages](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages). That simply has a build script that links to the appropriate libraries and exposes the C methods. It will use the [Cargo `links` key](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#the-links-manifest-key) to uniquely identify the native library and prevent linking to it multiple times. Other libraries can then include this new crate and not worry about those linking details.

Answer (score 21):

Another possible way is [setting the `RUSTFLAGS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads) like:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-L my/lib/location' cargo build # or cargo run
```

I don't know if this is the most organized and recommended approach, but it worked for my simple project.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answer is underrated!

Comment: is it possible to move the RUSTFLAGS into config files? I follow this document but did not work. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html @hbobenicio this is how I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250705/why-the-rustflags-parameter-in-cargo-toml-did-not-work-in-macos

Answer (score 6):

I found something that works OK: you can specify `links` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
links = "libsoundio"
build = "build.rs"
```

This specifies that the project links to `libsoundio`. Now you can specify the search path and library name in the `.cargo/config` file:

```
[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu.libsoundio]
rustc-link-search = ["libsoundio-1.1.0/i686"]
rustc-link-lib = [":libsoundio.a"]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.libsoundio]
rustc-link-search = ["libsoundio-1.1.0/x86_64"]
rustc-link-lib = [":libsoundio.a"]
```

(The `:` prefix tells GCC to use the actual filename and not to do all its idiotic `lib`-prepending and extension magic.)

You also need to create an empty `build.rs`:

```
fn main() {}
```

This file is never run, because the values in `.cargo/config` override its output, but for some reason Cargo still requires it - any time you use `links =` you have to have `build =`, even if it isn't used.

Finally in `main.rs`:

```
#[link(name = "libsoundio")]
#[link(name = "ole32")]
extern {
    fn soundio_version_string() -> *const c_char;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I get name for my target (I'm using Mac and Linux). Should I commit `.cargo/config` into version control or should it be different for every developer?

Comment: The target is set by rustup. Run `rustup show`. (Or you can override the default with something like `cargo --target blah`.) `.cargo/config` should be in version control. However most people seem to use a non-empty `build.rs` to do this, rather than `.cargo/config`.

Comment: the build.rs is required because has been specified in the [package] section to be used.