# Linking NTDLL in Rust application using Cygwin while targeting x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

Tags: rust, cygwin, gnu

I opened a pull request in [DarkEld3r's os_info repository](https://github.com/DarkEld3r/os_info/pull/45) to retrieve the actual Windows version and edition name.

The application needs to link to ntdll.dll in order to use [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723418(v=vs.85).aspx). The DLL is linked correctly when the target is set to `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` while using Cygwin and the normal Windows console. When the target is `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`, [the linker returns an error](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/DarkEld3r/os-info/build/1.0.152/job/tnnwdbqa5251a417):

```
   Running `rustc --crate-name print_version examples\print_version.rs --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=ec9720acb7c740b3 -C extra-filename=-ec9720acb7c740b3 --out-dir C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\examples -L dependency=C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\deps --extern kernel32=C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\deps\libkernel32-beacffc979f26c46.rlib --extern user32=C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\deps\libuser32-fbb28ae30109687c.rlib --extern winapi=C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\deps\libwinapi-bb7af3f2a31ea235.rlib --extern os_info=C:\projects\os-info\target\debug\deps\libos_info-c5887b186deb8679.rlib`
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostdlib" "-m64" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\crt2.o" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version0.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version1.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version10.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version11.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version12.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version2.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version3.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version4.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version5.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version6.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version7.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version8.rust-cgu.o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.print_version9.rust-cgu.o" "-o" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.exe" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\examples\\print_version-ec9720acb7c740b3.crate.allocator.rust-cgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\deps\\libos_info-c5887b186deb8679.rlib" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\deps\\libkernel32-beacffc979f26c46.rlib" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\deps\\libuser32-fbb28ae30109687c.rlib" "C:\\projects\\os-info\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-bb7af3f2a31ea235.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-60d4a252bdda9250.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-0b63e20460046692.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-7daa32005d584d8a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-49ff25caaa6e945f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc_system-a05404e5e059417a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-f824a78e715239af.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_unicode-2abaea46f194a6e1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librand-81cbf6f1d5a19206.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-f2bd2d524c6ace24.rlib" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-c6139fac5e899293.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-l" "ntdll" "-l" "kernel32" "-l" "user32" "-l" "advapi32" "-l" "ws2_32" "-l" "userenv" "-l" "shell32" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-l" "gcc_eh" "-l" "pthread" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "C:\\Users\\appveyor\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: ld: cannot find -lntdll
```

NTDLL.DLL is linked [on line 12 of this file](https://github.com/mattmccarty/os_info/blob/f066a67533aa49fb05499274b44d84dceb442af1/src/windows/version.rs).

I haven't found any questions regarding linking to NTDLL. I found [How do I specify the linker path in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833078/how-do-i-specify-the-linker-path-in-rust), but that solution didn't work for me either. I found the "libntdll.a" library in the `/usr/lib/w32api` directory of Cygwin, but it seems like GCC isn't using it.

Is there any way to get this to work on Windows while targeting GNU, or am I forced to use the MSVC target when linking system DLLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it by looking at the [winapi crate repository](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs).

Since, 0.2.8 of the crate doesn't support the RtlGetVersion() DLL function, I had to include libntdll.a in the repo. Once that's was done, I had to create a custom build script to include the source path of the library.

```

```
/// build.rs
/// Run custom functionality when a build executes
fn main() {
    use std::env::var;
    use std::path::Path;

    // When targeting x86_64-pc-windows-gnu, we need to include the DLL libraries
    // found in the lib/x86_64 directory
    if var("TARGET").map(|target| target == "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu").unwrap_or(false) {
        let dir = var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", Path::new(&dir).join("lib/x86_64").display());
    }

    // When targeting i686-pc-windows-gnu, we need to include the DLL libraries
    // found in the lib/i686 directory
    if var("TARGET").map(|target| target == "i686-pc-windows-gnu").unwrap_or(false) {
        let dir = var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", Path::new(&dir).join("lib/i686").display());
    }
}
```

```

Comment: *I had to include libntdll.a in the repo* — that seems like an extremely brittle solution.

Comment: Any other ideas @Shepmaster?

Comment: @mattmc Here's an alternative that works (Runtime dynamic linking): https://docs.rs/whoami/1.2.1/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/src/whoami/windows.rs.html#266-304

Answer (score 0):

The ntdll.dll file is not on the path by default for the GNU windows target, so you can add it by writing the following in a build.rs file:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!(r"cargo:rustc-link-search=C:\windows\system32");
}
```