# How to link a dynamic Rust library using only rustc and not cargo?

Tags: rust, linker, dynamic-linking, ffi

My `main.rs` looks like

```rust
// #[link(name = "lib")]
extern "C" {
    fn hello();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        hello();
    }
}
```

And `lib.rs`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

I have compiled `lib.rs` using `rustc --crate-type=cdylib lib.rs -o lib.so`

How do I link `lib.so` to `rustc main.rs` command ?

Comment: Apart from the reason that there is no reason that you should avoid cargo, you have to use `cdylib` instead ([rust reference chp 12](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html))

Comment: `cargo clean` && `cargo build -vv` to see with what arguments is `rustc` executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to match ABIs. When you use an `extern "C"` block, you need to declare your functions using the same ABI.

Name your dynamic library using the platform's conventions. Use `.dylib` on macOS, `.lib` on Windows, and `.so` on Linux. `rustc` will do this for you automatically if you don't provide a `-o` option.

Once you have built your dynamic library, you need to add it to the compiler's linker options. `rustc --help` has a list of the various compiler options. `-L` adds a directory to the search path and `-l` links to a specific library.

**lib.rs**

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

**main.rs**

```
extern "C" {
    fn hello();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        hello();
    }
}
```

Compiled and executed with:

```
$ rustc --crate-type=cdylib lib.rs
$ rustc main.rs -L . -l lib
$ ./main
Hello, World!
```

As I'm on macOS, I used `otool` to show that it's indeed dynamically linked:

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    liblib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

See also:

- [Linking Rust application with a dynamic library not in the runtime linker search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602708/155423)
- [How do I specify the linker path in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40833078/155423)

---

For completeness, here's "normal" linking of crates:

**lib.rs**

```
pub fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    lib::hello();
}
```

```
$ rustc --crate-type=rlib lib.rs
$ rustc main.rs --extern lib=liblib.rlib
$ ./main
Hello, World!
```

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Comment: When I execute `./main` after `rustc main.rs -L . -l lib`, I get the error `error while loading shared libraries: liblib.so: cannot open shared object file`, and `lld main` shows `liblib.so => not found`, is there a workaround rather then moving it to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: @sn99 [Linking Rust application with a dynamic library not in the runtime linker search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602708/155423) and [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/155423)

Comment: to be clear I added `#![feature(link_args)] #![link_args="-Wl,-rpath LOCATION_OF_LIB"]` in `main.rs` and it worked