# Why the rustflags parameter in cargo.toml did not work in macOS

Tags: rust

I built the rust `cargo 1.72.1 (103a7ff2e 2023-08-15)` project using this command in macOS with M1 chip like this:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-L ./src/so' cargo build
```

it works fine, now I did not want to pass the rustflags from the command every time I build, then I read the document https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html and add the rustflags in Cargo.toml like this:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-L ./src/so"]
```

it seems did not work. I cannot use `cargo build` to build the project. Am I missing something? What should I do to fixed this issue and just using cargo build to compile the project? I am sure run this command in the project root folder from terminal. I also tried to put this config into `project/.cargo/config.toml`, still could not work. Also tried to change the path to absolute path in `project/.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-L /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/src/so"]
```

could not work. Also tried this:

```
[build]
rustflags = [
    '-L', './src/so'
]
```

replace with the absolute path in `.cargo/config.toml` still did not work.

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-Lnative=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/src/so"]
```

also tried this:

```
[build]
rustflags = ['-C', 'link-arg=-L./src/so']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not put it in Cargo.toml. As explained in the top of the document you linked:

> ## Configuration
>
> This document explains how Cargo’s configuration system works, as well
> as available keys or configuration. For configuration of a package
> through its manifest, see the manifest format.
>
> ### Hierarchical structure
>
> Cargo allows local configuration for a particular package as well as
> global configuration. It looks for configuration files in the current
> directory and all parent directories. If, for example, Cargo were
> invoked in `/projects/foo/bar/baz`, then the following configuration
> files would be probed for and unified in this order:
>
> - `/projects/foo/bar/baz/.cargo/config.toml`
> - `/projects/foo/bar/.cargo/config.toml`
> - `/projects/foo/.cargo/config.toml`
> - `/projects/.cargo/config.toml`
> - `/.cargo/config.toml`
> - `$CARGO_HOME/config.toml` which defaults to:
>
>   - Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config.toml`
>   - Unix: `$HOME/.cargo/config.toml`

So put it in `.cargo/config.toml` (or another place from the list).

Comment: it looks like a issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4452